# Como impedir um comando

Tags: c#, radiobutton

Gostaria de evitar que o meu registro não fosse salvo se os `radiobutton` não estivessem selecionado.

Meu código:

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if ((rdbMasculino.Checked == false) && (rdbFeminino.Checked == false)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Preencha o Campo Sexo!");

        clnFuncionario Sexo = new clnFuncionario();

        Sexo.nome = txtNome.Text;
        if (rdbMasculino.Checked == true)
            Sexo.sexo = "Masculino";
        if (rdbFeminino.Checked == true)
            Sexo.sexo = "Feminino";

    } else {
        clnFuncionario Funcionario = new clnFuncionario();
        if (txtCodigo.Text != "") {
            Funcionario.cod_Funcionario = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);

        }

        Funcionario.sexo = rdbMasculino.Text;
        Funcionario.sexo = rdbFeminino.Text;

        if (ObjOperacao == clnFuncoesGerais.Operacao.Inclusao) {
            Funcionario.Gravar();

            MessageBox.Show("Dados Gravados com Sucesso! ", "Item novo " + txtNome.Text,
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Se nenhum dos `radiobutton` estiverem marcado, ele mostra a mensagem, porém, depois de mostrar a mensagem ele salva o registro mesmo assim. Gostaria que o registro só fosse salvo se um dos `radiobutton` estiverem selecionado e gostaria de saber se esse código que eu fiz está bom ou dá pra melhorar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez as linhas abaixo não sejam necessárias pois entra na condição de ambos os `radiobutton` não estarem marcados.

```
clnFuncionario Sexo = new clnFuncionario();

Sexo.nome = txtNome.Text;
if (rdbMasculino.Checked == true)
    Sexo.sexo = "Masculino";
if (rdbFeminino.Checked == true)
    Sexo.sexo = "Feminino";
```

O código pode ficar assim:

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if ((rdbMasculino.Checked == false) && (rdbFeminino.Checked == false)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Preencha o Campo Sexo!");

    } else {
        clnFuncionario Funcionario = new clnFuncionario();

        Funcionario.nome = txtNome.Text;

        if (rdbMasculino.Checked == true)
            Funcionario.sexo = "Masculino";
        if (rdbFeminino.Checked == true)
            Funcionario.sexo = "Feminino";

        if (txtCodigo.Text != "") {
            Funcionario.cod_Funcionario = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
        }

        if (ObjOperacao == clnFuncoesGerais.Operacao.Inclusao) {
            Funcionario.Gravar();

            MessageBox.Show("Dados Gravados com Sucesso! ", "Item novo " + txtNome.Text,
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente saia da função após exibir a mensagem de erro:

```
MessageBox.Show("Preencha o Campo Sexo!");
return; // sai da função
```